# devexpress pie chart showing percentage of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using a devexpress pie chart. There are 2 slices, with values 8 and 12 (out of a total of 20). 
when I use the code below, the values shown on slices are `0/4` and `0/6`, while I need the values to be `40%` and `60%`.

```
((PiePointOptions)series.LegendPointOptions).PointView = PointView.Values;
((PiePointOptions)series.LegendPointOptions).PercentOptions.ValueAsPercent = false;
```

Setting `ValueAsPercent = true` only makes things worse by changing the values to `0` and `1`!!! And showing the same proportions (`0/4` and `0/6`) on the slices.

How do I show percentage of each slice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example  see if it helps

```
// Create an empty chart.
        ChartControl pieChart = new ChartControl();

        // Create a pie series and add it to the chart.
        Series series1 = new Series("Pie Series", ViewType.Pie);
        pieChart.Series.Add(series1);

        // Add points to it.
        series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("A", new double[] { 0.3 }));
        series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("B", new double[] { 5 }));
        series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("C", new double[] { 9 }));
        series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("D", new double[] { 12 }));

        // Make the series point labels display both arguments and values.
        ((PiePointOptions)series1.Label.PointOptions).PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

        // Make the series points' values to be displayed as percents.
        ((PiePointOptions)series1.Label.PointOptions).PercentOptions.ValueAsPercent = true;
        ((PiePointOptions)series1.Label.PointOptions).ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
        ((PiePointOptions)series1.Label.PointOptions).ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;

        // Add the chart to the form.
        pieChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(pieChart);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :), I didn't know I need to set the properties of `series.Label` in order to change texts shown on slices.